# echo paginate_links() Numbers links wp

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

does any one know how to echo `paginate_links()` url ?

Eg :  Prev 1 2 3 4 Next

so i want to echo :

```
prev >> URL
1 >> URL
2 >> URL
```

Like this.
any one can help me.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$pagination = paginate_links(array(
    ....
    'type' => 'array',
));

var_dump($pagination);
```

WP is kinda tricky, but this should help :)

Comment: `$args = array(
            'base' => get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '%_%',
            'format' => $format,
            'current' => $paged,
            'total' => $kids->max_num_pages
        );
        echo paginate_links( $args );`

Comment: $args = array( 'type' => 'array', 'base' => get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '%_%', 'format' => $format, 'current' => $paged, 'total' => $kids->max_num_pages ); var_dump(paginate_links( $args ));

Comment: ok thank you this is working. i need little help.

i need to add those value to new array to chage as my self, how can i do that

` 0 => string '<span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>' (length=43)`

Comment: When you have it as an array, you'll handle it ;)